# Можно ли  отменить раздельное написание приложений?

Tags: раздельно-дефис

Я считаю, что этого делать нельзя, и вот почему.

1."Старик сторож" – это не исключение, а ОБЩИЙ ПРИНЦИП НАПИСАНИЯ ВСЕХ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЙ.
Сравним:

а) раздельное написание приложения в нормальной позиции перед определяемым словом (произношение с двумя ударениями): река Москва, царевич Иван, трава полынь, старик сторож;

б) дефисное написание приложения при инверсии (слитное произношение с одним ударением): Москва-река, Иван-царевич, полынь-трава, сторож-старик. 
Таким образом, по форме записи (и даже по слуху) мы можем определить, КАКОЕ СЛОВО ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕМ.

2.Вообще говоря, обобщенным значением дефисной формы является отражение на письме близкого смыслового единства слов. Например, через дефис пишутся существительные с сочинительной связью основ: вопросы-ответы, хлеб-соль, друзья-приятели. Если появляется оттенок подчинения, то основное существительное всегда пишется на первом месте, а менее значимое -  на втором: диван-кровать, музей-квартира.

3.Конечно, дело не обходится без особых случаев: 
А) злодейка-западня – авторский вариант: тесное слияние слов, «единый образ»; 
Б) чудо-гриб – приложение не склоняется и не может писаться раздельно.

4.Наибольшую трудность представляют написания вида  "француз-гувернер, персы-торговцы, осетин-извозчик, сын-школьник, дочь-студентка". Но здесь приложение ТАКЖЕ ВСЕГДА НАХОДИТСЯ НА ВТОРОМ МЕСТЕ, причем  статус слов может меняться: француз-гувернер – приложение обозначает профессию француза, гувернер-француз – приложение обозначает национальность гувернера.

Вот и всё решение, совсем не сложное. Если же будет введена новая орфография Лопатина, то вся эта стройная система значений будет разрушена.

Answer (score 1):

Серж, правило-то известное, но только однозначно ведущее к упрощению и примитивизации письма.

Вот, к примеру, сочетание "красавица-актриса", которое сейчас пишется только через дефис, имеет разное значение. В примере 1 приложением является актриса, а в примере 2 приложением является красавица. Только вот "новая орфография" это разное значение  выразить не может, соответственно, наши академики в 1956 году бережнее относились к языку и лучше его понимали.

(1)"Ресторан «Алатр» на Тверской работал исправно, и кавалеров, мечтающих посидеть в этом ресторане с темноокой красавицей-актрисой, было предостаточно (кавалеров интересует красавица).

(2)Бесспорно, режиссер утвердил красавицу-актрису на эту роль  за ее актерский талант (режиссера интересует актриса).

Comment: Вера, см.дополнение.

Comment: Мне логика современных лингвистов представляется, скорее,  антилогикой. Сравните:старик сторож,  река Москва, трава полынь и сторож-старик, Москва-река, полынь-трава - все сочетания построены по одной логике, а у наших грамматиков для каждого класса слов своя логика, или то, что им логикой кажется.

Comment: Вера, ну ведь  ваши примеры состоят из родового и видового слова, что нет в примере ''старик сторож''.

Comment: Это ОБЩАЯ ФОРМУЛА для сочетаний любого вида,  а нар+нар, нар+собств, вид+род - это только разные наполнители этой структурной формулы. Дефис обозначает тесную связь слов (слитное чтение с одним ударением) , а это возможно в двух случаях: (1)отношения однородные или близки к однородным (диван-кровать); (2) сущ.+ приложение (поэт-новатор). Если написание раздельное, то это приложение+ сущ.,  чтение с двумя ударениями. А в новой орфографии теперь приложение от сущ. не отличишь.

Answer (score 0):

Вера, хотя вопрос старый, скорее всего вы уже знаете о новом правиле, но все же отвечу.

Дефисное написание в пункте ***б*** согласно новым правилам ( по Лопатину) уже возможны.

сочетания с однословными приложениями, предшествующими определяемому слову, напр.: ***старик-отец, красавица-дочка***
См.: Академический справочник.

[image: Грамота.ру]